# Upload a file to a Dropbox account in C#

Tags: c#, windows, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive-api

Supposing I have a user's log in information for Dropbox (his e-mail and the password), how can I upload a file to his account from C#? Is there any way or should I try with another service like Skydrive or Google Drive?

Comment: You can, but you need a developer key. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576923/dropbox-com-api-for-net

Comment: Do you have any code supposing I get a developer key? I want something simple, I need only this functionality...

Comment: Once you get the dev key, you can read the API documentation for examples if how to do that.

Comment: @ValentinRadu to follow up the previous comments, make an attempt yourself and come back with specific issues or questions.  We won't write your code for you, but we're happy to have solve issues you are having with your own code.

Comment: OK, will give it a try and post any further questions here. I managed to get a developer key. Thanks and good luck with your projects!

Comment: First problem I have: I can't get a token using the Dropbox Token Autorization Tool provided with Sharpbox. When I allow my app to use my Dropbox account, it redirects me to a page at Codeplex which says Invalid URL. Is this a problem with the steps I perform or is Sharpbox's procedure down?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google Drive, the documentation is at https://developers.google.com/drive/, however, you should never ask for other users' credentials and instead use OAuth 2.0.

The [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/) includes C# snippets and there's also a complete ASP.NET MVC tutorial that you can use to get started: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet